# Chrome open DevTools, web workers don't run

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, android-8.0-oreo

I found a compatibility problem about Android 8 and Chrome 71~72.
Web Workers are executable before opening DevTools, but not work after opening DevTools.

The following is the test result.

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script id="worker" type="app/worker">
            addEventListener('message', function () {
              postMessage('some message');
            }, false);
          </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log('script-in')
            var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector('#worker').textContent]);
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            // console.log('scripe.url',url)
            var worker = new Worker(url);

            worker.onmessage = function (e) {
                console.log('onmessage-in')
                // console.log('onmessage.e', e)
                // e.data === 'some message'
                console.log('onmessage-end')
            };
            worker.postMessage('')
            console.log('script-end')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Execute JavaScript, and open DevTools afterwards:

[image]

Open DevTools first, then execute JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: See if you can find an [existing bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=component%3APlatform>DevTools+summary%3Aworker+&sort=-modified) or maybe post a new one.

Comment: I find have existing bug report [Issue 921059](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=921059),
Thinks